# how to perform CRUD operation in selected columns by clicking the checkbox using list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to perform crud operation on selected Columns. the selection is done by using checkbox
Explanation:
First i will click the checkbox after that i will perform CRUD operation on the selected fields alone using list and the remaining fields will be empty or null.
I need just an sample

Comment: I think you need to update this question with some more detail about what you are trying to do. Try working through some of the Microsoft MVC guides a bit and if you're still stuck come back here and post a bit more detail about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to follow an MVC tutorial. Try out this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: i know to crud operation on all columns .I need to do on selected columns and the remaining columns should be default or null value

Comment: If you are using something like Entity Framework to load your data into the MVC application like in the tutorial I linked then it will only update things that have changed. If you change some data on the entity and leave other data as it is then it will only update the things that have changed.

Comment: no I am not using Entity Framework. just using mvc alone